# how to use a environmental variable as Bind-Ip in mongo db configuration file (mongod.conf)

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, centos7

I'm a newbie in mongodb and As far as I have seen, we always pass constant IP values like 127.0.0.1 or 172.17.0.5 as Bind IP in mongod.conf file.

This is the bind ip configuration in my mongod.conf>

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.5  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

I have defined an environmental variable in /etc/environment file
DHOST= 172.17.0.5

When I try to give Below configuration in mongod.conf, I cannot connect to mongo shell:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, *$DHOST*  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

Please help me to add a ENV var as bind ip in mongo db configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pretty much always bind to IPv4 0.0.0.0 or IPv6 ::0 (that is, “all addresses”) for things that run inside Docker containers.  The `docker run -p` option has an optional field that can limit what IP address on the host a published port will bind to; the container can’t be reached directly from off-host without configuration like this and so trying to bind to specific interfaces within the container isn’t especially helpful.

Comment: Thanks David Maze for the informative response. But when we give Bind Ip as IPv4 0.0.0.0, lets say if we have three replica sets for the mongo db (and the three replica sets are three docker containers in the same host), how will be able to bind the replica sets with 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Each container is in its own network space, so they can all successfully use the same bind parameters without conflicting.